# Setting "Include Out of stock" filter like amazon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to add a filter in shop page, to show products as include out of stock as amazon website, as below. I am using AAPF by berocket plugin righht now.
[Advanced AJAX Product Filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/)

[image]

I have searched a lot. I didn't find any clue.

Comment: In woocommerce -> settings you have this option: "Out Of Stock Visibility" deselect it if selected, not sure that this solve your issue depends on your plugins

Comment: I know this option, but I wanted to show/hide them by filters in shop page. [red](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11368483/red)